# Visual studio не публикует проект в Docker Hub

Tags: docker, .net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

Всем доброго времени суток.

У меня есть проект Blazor Server. Я хочу развернуть его на VPS, на который, специально для этого, я установил Docker. Я создал репозиторий на Docker Hub, и пытаюсь опубликовать свой проект туда, но при публикации происходит ошибка:

> #13 [build 5/9] COPY [../RemoteDB_Blazor.Models/RemoteDB_Blazor.Models.csproj,
> ../RemoteDB_Blazor.Models/]
> #13 sha256:89816787f774f525a36f618067304d3b6859548b993d6758aa675dbe8033da58
> #13 ERROR: "/RemoteDB_Blazor.Models/RemoteDB_Blazor.Models.csproj" not found: not found
>
> #12 [build 4/9] COPY [../RemoteDB_Blazor.Server/RemoteDB_Blazor.Server.csproj,
> ../RemoteDB_Blazor.Server/]
> #12 sha256:a08b315bcd8b862b13d70068667381c30e447300352cc4dfd0f7fbb7bac3640a
> #12 ERROR: "/RemoteDB_Blazor.Server/RemoteDB_Blazor.Server.csproj" not found: not found
>
> #8 [build 1/9] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster@sha256:27df774804cbf186cd05d5d997078765aec2f78ca6f63499bd06a698e99ea46a
> #8 sha256:c0fcecaf2d1911186f9f39120424af2069a0069c26b082840a618ebbc1a60c02
> #8 CANCELED  [build 4/9] COPY [../RemoteDB_Blazor.Server/RemoteDB_Blazor.Server.csproj,
> ../RemoteDB_Blazor.Server/]:  [build 5/9] COPY
> [../RemoteDB_Blazor.Models/RemoteDB_Blazor.Models.csproj,
> ../RemoteDB_Blazor.Models/]: failed to compute cache key:
> "/RemoteDB_Blazor.Models/RemoteDB_Blazor.Models.csproj" not found: not
> found RemoteDB_Blazor E:\code\RemoteDBWeb\RemoteDB_Blazor\Dockerfile  0

Понимаю что ругается на то что не может найти .csproj файлы моих библиотек классов. Но они находятся в отдельных проектах от Blazor части, но в одном решении. Не понимаю что ему нужно. Все зависимости указаны. И компилируется нормально. Даже если просто компилировать в Docker то всё ок, а при публикации вот это.

Как поправить? Заранее спасибо.

P.S. -
Возможно проблема в Dockerfile.
Вот, на всякий случай, его содержимое:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["RemoteDB_Blazor.csproj", ""]
COPY ["../RemoteDB_Blazor.Server/RemoteDB_Blazor.Server.csproj", "../RemoteDB_Blazor.Server/"]
COPY ["../RemoteDB_Blazor.Models/RemoteDB_Blazor.Models.csproj", "../RemoteDB_Blazor.Models/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./RemoteDB_Blazor.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "RemoteDB_Blazor.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "RemoteDB_Blazor.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "RemoteDB_Blazor.dll"]

Структура проекта: 
Решение 
| |-RemoteDB_Blazor 
| |-RemoteDB_Blazor.sln 
| |-RemoteDB_Blazor.csproj 
| |-Dockerfile 
|  
|-RemoteDB_Blazor.Models 
| |-RemoteDB_Blazor.Models.csproj
| 
|-RemoteDB_Blazor.Server 
| |-RemoteDB_Blazor.Server.csproj
```

Comment: Возможно проблема в том, что тут имеется попытка копировать ресурс, находящийся вне текущего контекста докера (то бишь папки с `Dockerfile`). В аргументе COPY не должно быть `../`

Comment: @user7860670 я пробовал выносить dockerfile в общую папку, и, меняя пути, запускать сборку оттуда через командную строку.
 Я в этом не преуспел. В таком случае он даже основную папку видеть переставал.
Или я вас не понял? Как-то же можно собрать такой проект? В данном случае без "../" никак.

Comment: COPY работает только с содержимым папки, а которой лежит Dockerfile, если без `../` никак, то не используйте COPY.

Comment: @user7860670 не могли бы вы, пожалуйста, дать пример как это сделать без ../.
Я вообще, если честно, докером пользуюсь второй день. Пока не особо удачно. Был бы очень признателен за любой намёк.

Comment: Ну как обходной вариант можете попробовать вместо копирования подгружать файлы из репозитория.